# "I'm living a lifetime in every minute that we're together."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I'm living a lifetime in every minute that we're together.

quoted from the movie "Notebook"

**I have a trouble while interpreting the meaning of this sentence.**

I guess it means he is fully enjoying his life when he is together with her,

but **I'm curious about the meaning when the phrase "living a lifetime" is combined with the phrase "in every minute".**

Does it mean every minute feels like a separate and fresh(distinct) lifetime

or does it just mean he is living a time in his life (in every minute), that is "in every minute" just emphasize he is fully enjoying his lifetime.

Comment: Presumably it means life every minute with this person is supremely fulfilling, but I agree with you that it's weird phrasing. It sounds like the person he's with is the most boring person in the world (time doesn't fly when you're not having fun.) Like sitting through a boring presentation makes t i m e  s e e m  e n d l e s s. . .

Comment: It means every minute (60 seconds) is as important as your average life span (75 to 80 years).

Comment: It means that sometimes a director lets hackneyed phrases into the final cut. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not mean both?

I mean, when you fall in love with someone and are on your first date(say), do you ever look at your watch? And how many times do you , when you are in a lecture hall? The difference is, in a lecture, no matter how much interesting it is, when it crosses say an hour and a half, (even if everything you are learning is new and beautiful) you stretch yourself slightly from the current posture , and have a look at the watch. So *posture* may be the thing a part of your mind is getting "bored with"(metaphorically), even if the rest of the entire brain is consumed in the lecture.

In love, the lover want's to mean(scientifically) that not a single part of her body is getting bored, i.e. every moment is refreshing and rejuvenating for her.
Every single second feels new. You do not remember  a single event of your previous life,do you?(except in case you are extra special!) Every lifetime is independent(mathematically ;-) ).

**Lifetime in a minute** is also used as a metaphor to indicate her extreme happiness: she means the entire joys and happiness one experiences in a lifetime, combined together are equivalent to what she is experiencing every moment.